# Start Omegle Text chat through c# Webbrowser

Tags: c#, html, browser

I am working on a application that fetches the html from Omegle.com.
The problem is, I need it to start the text chat through code, but I can't figure it out ;)
Anyone got a solution? :)

Thanks!

Comment: @Davide: It's whatever people choose to use it for. There's a text chat option for more tame conversations, which is what the OP appears to be asking about. Regardless, I fail to see the relevance of your comment.

Comment: it's a comment with a question in it, not an answer, needs no vote and being a question I asked him, does not have to make you happy or satisfied about its relevance.

Comment: It's not porn chat, even though some people use it for that (which is not allowed).

Answer (score 0):

This will start a text chat:

```
Omegle.Document.GetElementById("textbtn").InvokeMember("click")
```

And this will send whatever you have typed in the chat textbox:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In Omegle.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
            If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("class=""sendbtn""") Then
                Element.InvokeMember("click")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Element
```

Please note that I've named my webbrowser `Omegle`.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked the website and i can see that the "start chat" button appears always in the same position. If your program is a windows forms program then you can just click that position through the code. just move the cursor to that specific position and send mouseclick action. 
You should inject their javascript to do it in another way, and i dont think that is possible.